# Ubuntu 14.04 : Nvidia GT 740 m Drivers not working

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, bluetooth

i have tried a lot of method to try running nvidia GT 740m on ubuntu 14.04 
but none of them works . My laptop is hp pavilion 15n-209tx . Nvidia works fine on windows . I need serious help to overcome this problem or suggest me alternate ubuntu so that my wifi , bluetooth as well as nvidia card is fully supported on linux kernel . I don't know why this problem is there with bluez too >

Answer (score 2):

Install the latest stable NVIDIA drivers for GT 740M from the repositories.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.
On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> ... enter  user name and password ...

Now execute the following commands :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

**Update addressing that something went wrong during the installation**

First uninstall all currently installed NVIDIA software you installed before.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - enter user name and password - execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Now install the latest official NVIDIA drivers 358 from the GPU drivers PPA.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - enter user name and password - execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Open NVIDIA X Server Settings (PRIME Profiles) to switch between graphics.

Comment: Every time I come to an Nvidia question, you always have given a good answer :) +1 @cl-netbox

Comment: Help me get out Black screen no display now.... Nothing working

Comment: @RahulRao : 1) Make sure that the NVIDIA card is connected properly. 2) Maybe you have to activate the NVIDIA adapter in BIOS. 3) Uninstall the currently installed NVIDIA software and install the latest official drivers - I updated the answer with instructions. :)

Comment: @cl-netbox  :(  i did all  the steps i restarted ubuntu  and purged nvidia * ubuntu running normal , i tested my card on windows working fine . nvidia is embedded on the motherboard ( laptop ) but unfortunately  nvidia not working  on ubuntu 14.04  :(

Comment: @cl-netbox 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
After lspci | grep "VGA"

Comment: @RahulRao : Please provide the output of this command : lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'

Comment: @cl-netbox 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2166
 Kernel driver in use: i915
--
0a:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 740M] (rev a1)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 21da
 Kernel driver in use: nouveau

Comment: @RahulRao : This tells you that the NVIDIA card is recognized by the system, but that still the open source drivers nouveau are in use. So the proprietary NVIDIA drivers installation failed. Please try it again - repeat the complete procedure exactly as described in the answer. :)

Comment: @cli-netbox is there any way to remove nouveau ( risk free ) and install nvidia driver because i want to learn developement with nvidia cuda

Comment: @RahulRao : When you install the NVIDIA drivers - nouveau drivers should be blacklisted and deactivated automatically. You can remove nouveau with : sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - and then install the NVIDIA drivers. You should this all from a virtual console : On login screen press Ctrl+Alt+F1. :)

Comment: @cli-netbox Thanks  , you are helping me a lot , i want to know more about the issue what probably the problem when i did all the steps and black screen occurs ( even after installing the drivers and disabling the nouveau on grub )

Comment: @RahulRao : This is very complex, generally video drivers installation is not a trivial thing and depends on the hardware environment (including the graphics adapters) which is different on nearly every machine. :)

Comment: @cli-netbox problem not fixed i purged all the nvidia* drivers . i also tried to change  to nvidia in the additional drivers  section it took me around 20 minutes to take  change the config but then i restarted the system , ran lspci | grep "VGA" still not working but pc working fine !

Comment: @RahulRao : I am running out of ideas - the instructions work in nearly all of the cases - maybe a complete clean installation of the whole system can solve the problem - when you decide to do this, the first action after installing Ubuntu should be to install the NVIDIA drivers. :)

Comment: @cli-netbox Thankyou , for your precious time .

Comment: **@RahulRao:** Don't thank **cl-netbox**!  **;-)** If this answer did help, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey ☑ *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, just [ask another one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)!